# Can a virtual image created by a mirror have position in front of the mirror?

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics, imaging

I dont think so, because then the rays will intersect and the image will be real.

Please let me know if you know a case in which a virtual image is formed in front of the mirror.

Comment: How many mirrors? What kinds?

Comment: Just one spherical mirror : Convex OR concave

Comment: Nope, not possible. They have to be such that it appears to be coming from behind the mirror, because there is nothing else behind. If it happened then where will you look at the image, lol. Just inagine how funny this is.

Answer (score 1):

If the image would be formed in front of the mirror it would not be a virtual image anymore, it would mean that your eye would have the impression to see it in front of the mirror. 
As soon as the ray is reflected, the eye which interprets light as travelling in straight line necessary sees the object as coming from behind the mirror and that is why the image is said to be virtual. 
So the answer to me is no.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence in your question is the answer. With a virtual image, the rays appear to come from an object behind the mirror. The important words there are "appear to." There is no actual object behind the mirror from which the rays are emanating. If there is a real image in front of the mirror and you view it from some distance away, the rays will "appear to" come from it, after they leave the image location, as though there were an object at that location. But, as you say, what you are seeing is the effect of a real image.